# Using Recursion to compute the number of something to print

Tags: java, recursion, exponent

I learning recursion and there is an example which I solve writing the * character a certain amount of times.

For example: if you were to pass in the number 3, it should print 2^3 stars so it would print out 8 stars.

I should print it 2 ^ k times where k is a passed integer. The answer to the question is:

```
public String printStars(int k) {
    if (k == 0) 
        return "*";
    else 
        return printStars(k - 1) + printStars(k - 1); 
}
```

I cant seem to understand the call stack and how that solves the problem, the way I view it, when I pass in 3 for int k, it would do n - 1 3 times till it hits the base case, and would return 2 stars to the call before that, and since it took 3 levels to get that deep, it would print 3 x 2 stars so it would print 6 stars. It's strange because most other recursion comes easily to me but this is confusing.

Comment: I assume you mean `k` instead of `n` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easy way to see it is to just expand each function call:

When k = 3 the `return` statement evaluates to `printStars(2) + printStars(2)`.

So it'll call the `printStars(2)` on the left first which will evaluate to:

`printStars(1) + printStars(1) + printStars(2)`

Again, let's expand the left one first:

`printStars(0) + printStars(0) + printStars(1) + printStars(2)`

`printStars(0)` will finally evaluate to `"*"` so we'd have

`"*" + "*" + printStars(1) + printStars(2)` == `"**" + printStars(1) + printStars(2)`.

And we've already seen that `printStars(1) == "**"` so we have:

`"****" + printStars(2)`. And we already know what `printStars(2)` will resolve to.

Comment: Thank you, I was following it through but forgot the original Call of printStars(#) needed to be added on to what you recurse with. so I was getting an answer that was the correct answer - what you get from the original call.  Thank you for explaining it that way

Answer (score 1):

I guess it must always be `k` or `n`?

How the recursion works: It spanns a tree:

Each call to printStars leads to one `*` (2^0) or two `*` (2^1).

If you call printStars(4):

Recursion level 4 ist != 0 so it returns the contraction of two separate calls of itself, each with parameter (3).

Recursion level 3 ist != 0 so it returns the contraction of two separate calls of itself, each with parameter (2).

Recursion level 2 ist != 0 so it returns the contraction of two separate calls of itself, each with parameter (1).

Recursion level 1 ist != 0 so it returns the contraction of two separate calls of itself, each with parameter (0).

Recursion level 0 ist == 0 so each call return with one `*`.

Back in recursion level 1 we receive two `*` and contract and return them.

Back in recursion level 2 we receive two `**` and contract and return them.

Back in recursion level 3 we receive two `****` and contract and return them.

Back in recursion level 4 we receive two `********` and contract and return them.

So the caller receives '***************' 2^4=16 *'s

```
caller                 |
k=4              /         \            (just call yourself 2 times an return contraction of both calls)
k=3          /     \     /     \        (just call yourself 2 times an return contraction of both calls)
k=2         / \   / \   / \   / \       (just call yourself 2 times an return contraction of both calls)
k=1        /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\      (just call yourself 2 times an return contraction of both calls)
k=0        ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **      (just return 2^0 = 1 '*')
```

Comment: Great diagram, thank you for your response, that makes the process very clear, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the code through:

It should be clear that in the non-base case:

```
printStars(k).length() == 2 * printStars(k - 1).length()
```

since the value in that case is given by

```
return printStars(k - 1) + printStars(k - 1);
```

Using this observation, we can prove by induction that:

```
printStars(k).length() == 2^k
```

(where `^` denotes power, rather than bitwise XOR)

- It is true in the base case that `printStars(0).length() == 2^0`
- Assuming that `printStars(k - 1).length() == 2^(k-1)`, `printStars(k).length() == 2 * printStars(k - 1).length() == 2^k`

QED.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that was very helpful!